# How do I get Draftjs Editor state inside API success

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs, fetch, draftjs

I want to get update the editor state when data fetched from the api how do I used DraftJS object inside the jquery Ajax/ fetch success 
it throw this error:

```
Request failed TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    at PageContainer.js:361
```

Line 361:  console.log(this.state.editorState2)

and this API request I am doing on Keypress

Comment: `this` is not defined in a function component, change it to a class component.

Comment: how to I do that @kiarashws

Comment: Add some code so I can help you.